# ORDER BY with diacritic in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by, diacritics

I need to select data from table and sort them with ORDER BY clause.
The problem is the column contains text data with czech diacritic.
I cannot use COLLATE, because the DB is part of postgres cluster which was created with lc_collate = en_US.UTF-8 and I cannot afford downtime caused by recreating the cluster with correct lc_collate.

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id serial PRIMARY key,
  name text
);

INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES ('Žoo'), ('Zoo'), ('ŽOO'), ('ZOO'),
  ('ŽoA'), ('ŽóA'), ('ŽoÁ'), ('ŽóÁ');
```

Ideal output:

```
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY name COLLATE "cs_CZ.utf8";
id | name
----+------
  2 | Zoo
  4 | ZOO
  5 | ŽoA
  7 | ŽoÁ
  6 | ŽóA
  8 | ŽóÁ
  1 | Žoo
  3 | ŽOO
(8 rows)
```

[Here](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/538076653.8311237444465698.JavaMail.root@vnr0) I found kind of solution:

```
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY name USING ~<~;
id | name
----+------
  4 | ZOO
  2 | Zoo
  3 | ŽOO
  5 | ŽoA
  1 | Žoo
  7 | ŽoÁ
  6 | ŽóA
  8 | ŽóÁ
(8 rows)
```

The result is close enough (for my usage) - the caroned letters are AFTER the non-caroned.

---

*My slightly off-topic Postgresql anabasis with `~<~` operator*

**edit**: turned into [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35807872/operator-in-postgres).

---

**Back to the question**: Is there other solution to get the ideal order besides recreating the postgres cluster with correct locale?

Also some insght on the `~<~` operator would be nice.

Comment: What is your postgres version?

Comment: BTW. You do not need downtime to use collation as in `ORDER BY name COLLATE "cs_CZ.utf8"`. You do not need downtime to add additional collation to existing postgres cluster: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createcollation.html

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. The downtime is unnecessary, all I needed was to add new locale on the server by adding line `cs_CZ.UTF-8 UTF-8` to `/etc/locale.gen` and regenerating locale with `locale-gen`. Then in Postgres: `CREATE COLLATION "cs_CZ.utf8" ( locale = 'cs_CZ.UTF-8' );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Igor pointed out in his comment, there is no need to recreate the postgres cluster with different *lc_collate* and deal with the caused downtime.

Exact steps that solved the problem were:

1. add/uncomment line `cs_CZ.UTF-8 UTF-8` in `/etc/locale.gen`
2. generate the new locale:

   `# locale-gen`
3. define new collation in postgres:

   `CREATE COLLATION "cs_CZ.utf8" ( locale = 'cs_CZ.UTF-8' );`

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if I understand the question, because look like you already found a solution. The only think I can suggest is you can add a new field `czechName` with the correct collate

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html

```
ADD [ COLUMN ] column_name data_type [ COLLATE collation ] [ column_constraint [ ... ] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what Juan Carlos Oropeza suggests, you can try to change the collation of the column with:

```
ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN "name" TYPE text COLLATE 'cs_CZ.utf8';
```

Reference: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html