# Operator ~<~ in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, sorting, pattern-matching, operators

<sup>(Originally part of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35629454/order-by-with-diacritic-in-postgres), but it was bit irrelevant, so I decided to make it a question of its own.)</sup>

I cannot find what the operator `~<~` is. The Postgres manual only mentions  `~` and similar operators [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP), but no sign of `~<~`.

When fiddling in the psql console, I found out that these commands give the same results:

```
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY name USING ~<~;
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY name COLLATE "C";
```

And these gives the reverse ordering:

```
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY name USING ~>~;
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY name COLLATE "C" DESC;
```

Also some info on the tilde operators:

```
\do ~*~
                                    List of operators
  Schema   | Name | Left arg type | Right arg type | Result type |       Description       
------------+------+---------------+----------------+-------------+-------------------------
pg_catalog | ~<=~ | character     | character      | boolean     | less than or equal
pg_catalog | ~<=~ | text          | text           | boolean     | less than or equal
pg_catalog | ~<~  | character     | character      | boolean     | less than
pg_catalog | ~<~  | text          | text           | boolean     | less than
pg_catalog | ~>=~ | character     | character      | boolean     | greater than or equal
pg_catalog | ~>=~ | text          | text           | boolean     | greater than or equal
pg_catalog | ~>~  | character     | character      | boolean     | greater than
pg_catalog | ~>~  | text          | text           | boolean     | greater than
pg_catalog | ~~   | bytea         | bytea          | boolean     | matches LIKE expression
pg_catalog | ~~   | character     | text           | boolean     | matches LIKE expression
pg_catalog | ~~   | name          | text           | boolean     | matches LIKE expression
pg_catalog | ~~   | text          | text           | boolean     | matches LIKE expression
(12 rows)
```

The 3rd and 4th rows is the operator I'm looking for, but the description is a bit insufficient for me.

Comment: This operator is being used by Postgres for lookup if you have an index with opclass. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/indexes-opclass.html

Comment: Create an index on `test (name text_pattern_ops)` and look at the `EXPLAIN` output for `name LIKE 'abc%'`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`~>=~`, `~<=~`, `~>~` and `~<~` are `text` pattern (or `varchar`, basically the same) operators, the counterparts of their respective siblings `>=`, `<=`, `>`and `<`. They sort character data **strictly by their byte values**, ignoring rules of any collation setting (as opposed to their siblings). This makes them faster, but also invalid for most languages / countries.

The "C" locale is effectively the same as *no locale*, meaning no collation rules. That explains why `ORDER BY name USING ~<~` and `ORDER BY name COLLATE "C"` end up doing the same. The latter syntax variant should be preferred: more standard, less error-prone.

Detailed explanation in the last chapter of this related answer on dba.SE:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)

Note that `~~` / `~~*` are Postgres operators for [`LIKE` / `ILIKE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) and *barely related* to the above. Similarly, `!~~` / `!~~*` for `NOT LIKE` / `NOT IILKE`. (Use standard `LIKE` notation instead of these "internal" operators.)

Related:

- [~~ Operator In Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925796/operator-in-postgres)
- [Symfony2 Doctrine - ILIKE clause for PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784261/symfony2-doctrine-ilike-clause-for-postgresql/13784311#13784311)
- [Find rows where text array contains value similar to input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657669/postgresql-text-array-contains-value-similar-to/34658431#34658431)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, especially for pointing out the relation to the `COLLATE "C"`.
I even read your answer on dba.SE prior to asking my question, but somehow I missed the part with `~<~` operator.